# Перенаправление вывода в файл

Tags: c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, как внутри C++ программы можно перенаправить весь вывод в файл?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files

```
std::ofstream out("out.txt"); //откроем файл для вывод
std::streambuf *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); //запомним старый буфер
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); //и теперь все будет в файл out.txt!
```

// где то по желанию восстановим все на место

```
std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
```